# Derivative of Logs Discrepancy

Tags: calculus

First Principles state:

$$ d ln(Y) = \frac {1}{Y} $$

the proof makes sense and no complaints. However,

$$ d ln(Y) = ln ( \frac {Y_{t+\epsilon}}{Y_t} ) = ln ( Y_{t+\epsilon}) - ln(Y_t) = \frac {dY}{Y} $$

a different result!

**How to reconcile the discrepancy?**

Comment: Are you deriving in order to $Y$? Because the second result is correct and implies the first if you are deriving in terms of $Y$ since then d$Y$ = 1

Comment: Yes, in order to $ Y $. I think this makes sense now because the idea of derivatives is to measure rates of change over infitesimal intervals. Hence, $ dY $ closely approximates 1. Is this an accurate statement, @user6767509?

Comment: The statement is accurate as long as you mention that dY approximates 1 beacuse you are measuring the rate of change in order to Y. You are relating how much Y changes as Y changes.

Comment: Which explains why $ dY $ is geometrically asymptotic to $ Y $. Instantaneous change is a $ 1:1 $ correspondence in order to $ Y $. Many thanks for clarifying what must have been a trivial thing, @user6767509.